# How i can get a value field from a foreignkey field properly

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

i want to get a value field (named "`width`") from `foreignkey` field named `square`(last selectable choice by the user) exist on my form:

Here is the code line that i have used it to get this value("width"):

```
width = float(FormulaireIng.objects.get(square = FormulaireIng.objects.last()).values_list('width'))
```

Here is the **models.py**:

```
class FormulaireIng(models.Model): 
    square = models.ForeignKey(Square, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Square(models.Model): 
    width = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Width", max_length=50)
```

an error displayed after developing that:

```
ValueError at /pdf/
Cannot query "4.0": Must be "Square" instance.
```

How i can get a value field from a foreignkey field properly from a model.

Thanks in advance.

Edited the function where am trying to get on it the field value "width" from the model:

```
def forms_render_pdf_view(request, *args, **kwargs):   
    template_path = 'pdf.html'  
    width = float(FormulaireIng.objects.get(square = 
    FormulaireIng.objects.last()).values_list('width'))
    design = (2/8) / width
    context = {'design': design}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this again. Should work now

```
formulaire_object = FormulaireIng.objects.all().last()
square = formulaire_object.square
width = square.width
```

Answer (score 0):

The error shows clearly what the problem is. It should be a Square instance and not FormulaireIng instance. You're looking for 'width' which is in Square model, so how about querying the Square model directly. You can pass in the id of the square object and get the width.

```
width = Square.objects.get(id=id).width
```

Comment: Hi, this suggestion of  solution, gives me error :TypeError at /pdf/
Field 'id' expected a number but got <built-in function id>.       Another thing I have set "width = FormulaireIng..." because the "square" model is a field from this model "FormulaireIng" .Also what i want is getting the field-value("width") related to the last  foreignkey field  that belongs to the ""FormulaireIng"" model on the form.

Comment: Can you share your function or whatever you are doing to query the model